# Nomenclature for number of self-references in a recursive sequence

Tags: recurrence-relations, terminology, recursion

I am looking for a word that denotes the number of self-references in a recursive sequenece. For example, the Fibonacci sequence is defined by the recurrence relation $F_n = F_{n-1} + F_{n-2}$, and so it could be said that the *word I am looking for* of the Fibonacci sequence is 2.

I have scoured the Wikipedia articles on sequences and recursion, without coming across a satisfactory answer. Intuitively, I would go for something along the lines of *recursion depth*, but this already has a different meaning in computer science.

Comment: See whether you get anything here: http://homepages.math.uic.edu/~kauffman/SelfRefRecurForm.pdf

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The term you're looking for is *order*.

For instance, the Fibonacci sequence is a homogeneous linear recurrence of order $2$.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constant-recursive_sequence#Definition.